# C and D 300 Gb drives in one machine How to install on D and do dual boot?

Tags: system-installation

I have two 300 Gb hard drives in the same Pentium based machine - C and D. Drive C is currently running Windows 8. I want to install Ubuntu on drive D  Can I do that? How would I select which drive (OS) I want to boot from? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicated: [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/q/221835/62483)

Answer (score 0):

You can, it may be a bit tricky.

Here's what I'd do:

1. Go to "Disk Management" (on win7 it's right-click-on-computer->manage->disk management, should be the same for win8).
2. Delete all volumes on D (or delete some of the volumes to provide space for Ubuntu).
3. Put Ubuntu in and restart.
4. Choose "install Ubuntu alongside *".
5. If you see any partition, your seeing the wrong disk. Just use the "select drive" chooser to choose the disk you deleted.
6. Finish installation as you like.
7. After all is done, if you are not happy with the way your machine boots restart into BIOS setup (usually click F1 or DEL many times when machine starts) and look for a "boot-sequence" setting- Check your motherboard manual to see where it is if necessary, choosing this setting will show you a list of boot options, two of them should be your two hard drives. Just swap the first hard-drive with the second than save & exit. You should be okay.

Comment: The installation of Ubuntu using dual-boot system over a Windows 8 installed system is quite different than Windows 7. This OS differ in the boot technology

Comment: The question is mainly about how to partition and dual-boot, and we are talking about two separate hard drives. In such a case win8 boot system can simply be bypassed by setting the boot-sequence in the BIOS.